# Having trouble getting the .change class to remove from from navbar links after they are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I'm trying to implement a sticky navigation bar that adds and removes a .change class to link elements as the user scrolls up and down the page. It seems to work for the most part, however, when the link items are clicked and then the screen is scrolled away the .change does not remove from the clicked link. It still adds and removes to other links as the screen is scrolled but the clicked link remains changed (it does remove when a different link is clicked however, but then that new link is stuck with .change). Please help....

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-link');

sections.forEach((section, i) => {

  if (window.pageYOffset >= (section.offsetTop - 200)) {
    navbarLinks.forEach(navbarLink => {
      navbarLink.classList.remove('change');
      navbarLink.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
    })
    navbarLinks[i].classList.add('change');
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar-link {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.navbar-link::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: .2rem;
  background-color: var(--grey-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: -9%;
  bottom: -.2rem;
  transition: width .2s;
}

.navbar-link:hover {
  color: var(--grey-color)
}

.navbar-link:hover::before {
  width: 120%;
}

.change.navbar-link {
  color: var(--grey-color)
}

.change.navbar-link::before {
  width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar center">
  <a href="#home" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
  <a href="#about" class="navbar-link">About</a>
  <a href="#projects" class="navbar-link">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="navbar-link">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

I expected the .change class to be removed when the screen scrolls, away as it otherwise does when link has not been clicked. I tried removing the class specifically from the clicked item as well as removing pointer events but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is that code inside an event listener?

Comment: This is vanilla JS, not jQuery.

Comment: There's no `<section>` in the HTML.

Comment: I could swear I didn't select jQuery and I've seen other people make that mistake but I guess I did, sorry. The code is inside of an event listener on the window (I didn't think I would be able to post the complete file) and there are section tags in the html.                                               
    window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
    mainFn()
});

Comment: I feel like there is something fundamental I'm missing about what happens to a link after it's clicked but I tried selecting const navbarLinkHovers = document.querySelectorAll('navbar-link:hover') and then removing .change from those as well thinking that maybe .change was being combined with the pseudo class but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things to make this work

#### 1. You need some HTML tags to detect

In your case, your HTML was missing some `<section>` tags. I have added in the four that you need to match your Navbar links.

#### 2. You need a way to make your function keep re-running

I have added an ugly method, namely `setInterval`. It would be better to give your function a name, and add an event listener on scroll events, for example, which would avoid it being called when unnecessary. e.g.

```
<body onscroll="NAMEOFYOURFUNCTION">
```

There are even more advanced selective listeners that would not even fire on most scroll events where not necessary.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-link');

setInterval(()=>{
sections.forEach((section, i) => {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= (section.offsetTop - 200)) {
    navbarLinks.forEach(navbarLink => {
      console.log(navbarLink)
      navbarLink.classList.remove('change');
      navbarLink.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
    })
    navbarLinks[i].classList.add('change');
    console.log("Enabled `change` only on navbar link #",i)
  }
});
},1000)
```

```css
.navbar-link {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.navbar-link::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: .2rem;
  background-color: var(--grey-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: -9%;
  bottom: -.2rem;
  transition: width .2s;
}

.navbar-link:hover {
  color: var(--grey-color)
}

.navbar-link:hover::before {
  width: 120%;
}

.change.navbar-link {
  color: var(--grey-color)
}

.change.navbar-link::before {
  width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar center">
  <a href="#home" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
  <a href="#about" class="navbar-link">About</a>
  <a href="#projects" class="navbar-link">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="navbar-link">Contact</a>
</nav>
<section>
Hello
<br>
a
<br>
b
<br>
c
<br>
d
<br>
e
<br>
f
<br>
g
<br>
h
</section>
<section>
Hello
<br>
a
<br>
b
<br>
c
<br>
d
<br>
e
<br>
f
<br>
g
<br>
h
</section>
<section>
Hello
<br>
a
<br>
b
<br>
c
<br>
d
<br>
e
<br>
f
<br>
g
<br>
h
</section>
<section>
Hello
<br>
a
<br>
b
<br>
c
<br>
d
<br>
e
<br>
f
<br>
g
<br>
h
</section>
```